# SQL - multiple incognito parameters from single cell

Tags: sql, excel

I've been searching for this "issue" but I couldn't find anything. I'm not sure about how to explain it so, maybe I searched it in a wrong way. 
If not... I have this SQL embedded to an Excel spreadhseet

```
SELECT
PlanNo

FROM
tablex

WHERE
PlanNo IN ('12312','123',1456')
```

I would like to set the "WHERE" in order to link it to a cell in my excel spreadsheet but if I do this below in order to have multiple parameters taken from a single cell, it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
PlanNo

FROM
tablex

WHERE
PlanNo IN = ?
```

I try to put these below into, for instance, my cell B2 but I can't make it work.

```
'7090001701','7090001512'
"7090001701","7090001512"
('7090001701','7090001512')
("7090001701","7090001512")
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much in advance,
cheers

Comment: `IN = ` doesn't seem to make much sense. Is the value `IN` a range of values or is it `equal to` a specific value? Also, what does `can't make it work` mean? Are you getting an error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant
PlanNo IN ?

Hi, I don't have any error, just no results. What I'd like is to have as many values as I have in a single cell but I don't know which format recognize the excel embedded Sql. I don't want to put something like this: WHERE PlanNo LIKE = ? OR PlanNo LIKE = ? OR PlanNo LIKE = ? etc...

Comment: You will have to write VBA code for that, unfortunately. In VBA, you can take value of B2, split it up by comma and build your SQL statement.

Comment: Oh, I see.. Do you have any example for me or link where  i can check how to do that? My VBA level is not that good. Thank you so much for yoy answer